# Can't get Symfony 2 to work with PHPstorm

Tags: php, symfony, phpunit, phpstorm, jetbrains-ide

I've installed the symfony plugin to PHPstorm, but when I'm trying to run the project I get the following error

```
Fatal error: Class 'Doctrine\Tests\Common\Cache\CacheTest' not found in ...
```

[image]

I've checked the path and CacheTest file is in the correct folder. When I run the symfony project from the command line it works just fine.

Is there someway to fix this problem?

Comment: did you install the vendors?

Answer (score 2):

What you try is not correct. You execute the `php.exe` and that is the normal PHP executable. To run your Unit-Tests you need PHPUnit to run.

Go to `Preferences -> Languages & Frameworks -> PHP -> PHPUnit`  and define the phpunit.phar.

[image]

When you've done that you create a new configuration to run PHPUnit and you define the configuration which is under `app/phpunit.xml`.

[image]

Comment: I figured it out and added the answer where I mention your method for configuring phpunit.

Answer (score 1):

I figured it out. First of all you need add phpunit.phar as Stony explained in his answer.

After that all I really needed to do was to rename `phpunit.xml.dist` to `phpunit.xml` in `app/` folder and then just right click it and choose the `Run 'phpunit.xml'` option. This way the Tests succeed and it doesn't give any errors.

As for running the symfony project you need to add symfony command line tool support to phpstorm. All about that in this link: https://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/PhpStorm/Symfony2+Command+Line+Tool+Integration+-+Symfony+Development+using+PhpStorm

After that you just run it as a command like you would with normal command line. That's also explained in the link.

Comment: You don't need phpunit.xml to make this work, you just point the `phpunit.xml.dist` in the `Default configuration file` input in the phpunit configuration.

Answer (score 0):

Try to choose "Use custom autoloader" option in `Preferences -> Languages & Frameworks -> PHP -> PHPUnit` and specify the path to `vendor/autoload.php` file.